# Only allow 1 open entry at a time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a game which works with php and jquery through ajax.

Essentially, when a request is made to the server the server will create a new game if there is not already one open. My database table for the games looks as follows:

```
id | closed | time
```

Where closed will be set to 1 once a game is over, and time is the unix timestamp of when the game was created.

Now the important thing here is that at any given time there can only be 1 game with closed = 0 in the table.

To do this I am using the following php code

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM games WHERE closed = '0' LIMIT 1";
$result = $this->database->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO games_roulette SET time = '".time()."'";
    $result = $this->database->query($query);
    return $this->database->insert_id;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The thing is occasionally 2 games will be created, I believe due to 2 requests being sent at the exact same time, as the time values are always the exact same when there are 2 games open.

Is there any way I can have 100% certainty that there will never be 2 games with closed = 0 in the table?

Comment: you could lock the table before the select and unlock it after the insert. i would bet there are better options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason you end up with 2 records is, as you suspect, concurrency. If 2 processes separately run the `SELECT` query first, they'll both get the green light to proceed, and they'll both run the `INSERT`. So you end up with 2 (or more!) such rows.

Traditionally, you'd use transactions or locks to avoid this, but there's also an SQL "trick" that would allow a single atomic query to accomplish this:

```
INSERT INTO
  game_roulette
SELECT NULL, x.closed, NOW()
  FROM
    (SELECT '0' as closed) x
    LEFT JOIN game_roulette g ON x.closed = g.closed
  WHERE
    g.id IS NULL
```

Just to explain how this works: it's an `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, where the `SELECT` query only yields a result if there's no row where `game_roulette.closed` is `'0'`. This, in turn, is done by creating a single row table `x`, then doing a `LEFT JOIN` against `game_roulette` on `closed` column and using the `g.id IS NULL` constraint.

After the completion of this query, if needed, the application can check the result of the `INSERT`, just as it would do for any other, to know if any row(s) were inserted as a result.

Note: if you're doing this on a large table, you should measure the query performance and/or make sure there's an index on `closed` column and it's getting used.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.